# How to parse JSON Array to Webview Android

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress, webview

I have this JSON data

```
"posts":[{
"date":"2016-02-10 10:28:42",
"categories":[{}],
"tags":[],
"author":{"name":"admin"},
"custom_fields":{
                 "ref_number":["ITB NUMBER: ITB\/002\/2016"],
                 "deadline":["26 February, 2016"],
                 "entity":["Refugees (xxx)"]
                }
```

I want to pass `entity`with the code below in my `JSONParser.java`

```
            Post post = new Post();
            // Configure the Post object
            post.setTitle(postObject.optString("title"));


            post.setDate(postObject.optString("date", "N/A"));
            post.setContent(postObject.optString("content", "N/A"));
post.setCfs(postObject.getJSONObject("custom_fields").optJSONArray("entity").getString(0));
```

to my **Webview**. using the code below in my `PostFragment.java`

```
id = args.getInt("id");

                //Title and date pass successfully
                title = args.getString("title");
                String date = args.getString("date");

               //but the entity displays null
                entity = args.getString("entity");

                //author is passed and it displays well/successfully
                String author = args.getString("author");

                 // Construct HTML content

                // html for entity to webview
                html += "<h2>" + entity + "</h2>";

                html += "<h3>" + title + "</h3>";
                // The actual content
                html += content;
```

am able to pass and display `title` and `content`, however when i try `entity` it shows `null` in webview

Where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
entity = args.getString("custom_fields.entity");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That didnt help either, still displays null

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear , as per my understanding you need `Refugee` element

The `JSON` you have posted is not valid.

As per my understanding  elements of `entity` is also an `JSONObject` , so the parser should be like this

```
.optJSONArray("entity").getJSONObject(i); // i is poistion
```

This will give you `ith` element of **entity** `array`